# Linq query will not let me order by a date

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query -

```
var data = (from req in db.tblRequirements
       where req.guidRequirementId == guidRequirementId
             && (!db.ViewMIPRAlls.Any(x=>x.guidRequirementId == req.guidRequirementId))
       select new
       {
           guidRequirementId = req.guidRequirementId,
           strStatus = req.tblCodesRequirementStatus.strDescription,
           strNumber = req.ViewNumber.strAwardNumber,
           strOffice = req.tblOrganization.strAcronym,
           strCustomerOffice = req.tblOrganizationCustomer.strAcronym,
           strDescription = req.strDescription,
           strNotes = req.strNotes,
           strStatusId = req.strStatusId,
           strCompany = req.strCompany,
           strUpdatedBy = Person.GetPersonNameFromUserID(req.guidUserId),
           dtmUpdated = Requirement.UpdateTime(req.guidRequirementId),
           dtmEsitmatedEnd = (req.tblDates.Select(x=>x.dtmEnd) != null
              ? req.tblDates.Select(x=>x.dtmEnd.ToShortDateString()).ToString()
              : ""
           )
       }).OrderBy(x=>x.dtmEnd);
```

and I am unable to order it by date.  This query results in the following error:

> Could not format node 'ClientQuery' for execution as SQL.

Comment: Which LINQ provider? LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either Orderby Before the select, or Orderby by something you've created in the select

Comment: When I put the order by before the select new I get the following error:
Cannot order by type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.DateTime]'.

Comment: (this means your app will do the ordering instead of the database)

Comment: it will probably do a lot more database accesses as well

Comment: or actually, keep it as it was, put dtmEnd in your select, then at the end do .ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.dtmEnd)

Comment: If that doesn't work, with your original code, if you take away the orderby and put ToList(),  does it work?

Answer (score 3):

The `OrderBy` clause should come before the `select new` if you try to sort by fields in SQL.

Your LINQ statement could be transformed in:

```
var data = 
    from req in db.tblRequirements
    from dates in req.tblDates
    where req.guidRequirementId == guidRequirementId
         && (!db.ViewMIPRAlls.Any(x=>x.guidRequirementId == req.guidRequirementId))
    order by dates.dtmEnd
    select new
    {
        guidRequirementId = req.guidRequirementId,
        strStatus = req.tblCodesRequirementStatus.strDescription,
        strNumber = req.ViewNumber.strAwardNumber,
        strOffice = req.tblOrganization.strAcronym,
        strCustomerOffice = req.tblOrganizationCustomer.strAcronym,
        strDescription = req.strDescription,
        strNotes = req.strNotes,
        strStatusId = req.strStatusId,
        strCompany = req.strCompany,
        strUpdatedBy = Person.GetPersonNameFromUserID(req.guidUserId),
        dtmUpdated = Requirement.UpdateTime(req.guidRequirementId),
        dtmEsitmatedEnd = (req.tblDates.Select(x=>x.dtmEnd) != null
            ? req.tblDates.Select(x=>x.dtmEnd.ToShortDateString()).ToString()
            : ""
        )
    }
```

Please note that depending on the type of relationship between `tblRequirements` and `tblDates`, this may yield more records than your initial select.
To overcome this, you'll need to think of a way to aggregate the records in `tblDates` corresponding to a `tblRequirements` record (perhaps just take `max(tblDates.dtmEnd)`?)

Comment: When I put the order by before the select new I get the following error: Cannot order by type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.DateTime]'.

Comment: @EvanGWatkins That's because you select from `tblRequirements`, but order by a field that's in `tblDates`. You need to get `tblDates` as well in the `from` clause (by joining it with the other table perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
where req.guidRequirementId == guidRequirementId
        && (!db.ViewMIPRAlls.Any(x=>x.guidRequirementId == req.guidRequirementId))
order by req.dtmEnd     
select new
```